# Update from gradle 6 to gradle 7 - CreateStartScrips migration

Tags: gradle

I just (yeah I know, pretty late) swapped to Gradle 7.5. I am having a really hard time changing the `CreateStartScripts` portion.

This is what I have

```
task serverStartScripts(type: CreateStartScripts) {
    applicationName = project.name
    outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'scripts')
    classpath = jar.outputs.files + project.configurations.runtimeClasspath
    mainClassName = 'blah.blah.Blah'

    doLast {
        def winFileText = windowsScript.text
        def unixFileText = unixScript.text
        def baseDir = "${buildDir}/install/${projectName}"

        def args = "-mainConf ${baseDir}/conf/m.properties -fedConf ${baseDir}/conf/m.f.properties -nodeConfYAML ${baseDir}/conf/m-nodes.yaml -cacheDir ${projectDir}/../server/cache/ -typeConfYAML ${baseDir}/conf/f-message_types.yaml"

        // Remove too-long-classpath and use pathing jar instead
         winFileText = winFileText.replaceAll('set CLASSPATH=.*', 'rem CLASSPATH declaration removed.')
         winFileText = winFileText.replaceAll('set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=', 'set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true')
         winFileText = winFileText.replaceAll('("%JAVA_EXE%" .* -classpath ")%CLASSPATH%(" .*)', '$1%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\' + pathingJar.archiveName + '$2')
         winFileText = winFileText.replaceAll('set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*', 'set CMD_LINE_ARGS=' + args)


         unixFileText = unixFileText.replace('APP_ARGS=.*', 'APP_ARGS=\"' + args + '\"')

         windowsScript.text = winFileText
         unixScript.text = unixFileText
    }
}
```

But really it is not replacing anything... I guess the template has changed and I have look at the [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html#org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts), but tbh I don't understand it.

I have managed to add

```
defaultJvmOpts = ['-Xms1024m', '-Xmx1024m', '-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true']
```

But how do I add command line arguments to the script? Is that not a good practice anymore? Or is there a different way to do it? They pretty much never change, thats the reason I want to have it as a part of the start script.